# ldap component Symfony3 configuration and set up

Tags: php, symfony

Writing Symfony3 app and trying to config symfony/ldap component to authenticate users and retrieve user attributes from my AD server.

so as i understand i need to install the [ldap component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/ldap.html#installation) first:

```
composer require symfony/ldap
```

Once this installed I need to Configure the [ldap client](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/ldap.html):

```
app/config/services.yml:

services:
    ldap:
        class: 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap'
        arguments:
            - ldap.forumsys.com # host
            - 389         # port
            - 3           # version
            - false       # SSL
            - true        # TLS

app/config/security.yml:

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        my_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: ldap
                base_dn: dc=example,dc=com
                search_dn: "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com"
                search_password: password
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: uid

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html
```

Ps. in services.yml I put a class as:

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
```

not:

```
Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient
```

as LdapClient is deprecated

Either way I get this error:

```
ServiceNotFoundException in CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 58:
The service "security.firewall.map.context.main" has a dependency on a non-existent service "ldap".
```

I understand the error saying that the ldap service declared in my sertvices.yml does not exist which is not the case.... Any idea why am seeing this error anything wrong with the set up...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey All well I managed to find the solution to this problem basically it was due to my Symfony version 3.0.9 and it has to be 3.1.0 or above.

Comment: I am runing into another issues will create another question and post the link here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884448/symfony3-ldap-component-adapterinterface-error

Comment: You might also need to run `composer update`. Hopefully this is a development environment.

Answer (score 1):

In your services.yml file, have you tried without quotes like this:

```
services:
    ldap:
        class: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
```

I'm not sure that's the correct way to specify the class.

Comment: The error is something to do with you services.yml file Tomazi; you need to figure out what that is. I'm not sure what else could be wrong.