# Symfony3 ldap component AdapterInterface error

Tags: php, symfony

I have posted a question recently on Symfony3 ldap component: [ldap question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837710/ldap-component-symfony3-configuration-and-set-up/37846631?noredirect=1#comment63182654_37846631)

I found the solution for it but because the previous question was so big and different I decided to ask another and link them together. Hopefully this is allowed.

Quick introduction: I am writing a Symfony3 app that needs a ldap authentication. Installed Symfony3 ldap component followed the documentation but i end up with this error:

```
    Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 

Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap::__construct() must be an instance of 

Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\AdapterInterface, string given, called in 

/Users/user.name/Dev/ldapTest/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php 
on line 1644 and defined
```

All the details are in the previous question check the link above.

**Update**

Code frome line 1644:

```
    /**
 * Gets the 'ldap' service.
 *
 * This service is shared.
 * This method always returns the same instance of the service.
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap A Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap instance.
 */
protected function getLdapService()
{
    return $this->services['ldap'] = new \Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap('ldap.forumsys.com', 389, 3, false, true);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code in question around line 1644 so we can see what might be the problem?

Comment: Sure check my update

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the correct way to call it:

```
protected function getLdapService()
{
    return $this->services['ldap'] = new \Symfony\Component\Ldap\LdapClient('ldap.forumsys.com', 389, 3, false, true);
}
```

Try it out, not certain though.